# VF - Can you create a multi-page wizard to save a single record?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I have setup a wizard that uses multiple VF pages and a single custom controller to guide the user through a user-friendly form and create a single custom object record. I tested out the wizard but when the `saveApplication` method that inserts the record is called, I don't see any new records in Salesforce - is it possible to create a multi-page wizard to gather inputs on different pages and save a single record?

Apex Controller for all pages

```
public without sharing class FormClass {
    
    //Application
    public Application__c app {
        get {
            if(app == null) 
                app = new Application__c();
            return app;       
        }
        set;
    }
    
    //NYS ID
    public Attachment ID {
        get {
            if(ID == null)
                ID = new Attachment();
            return ID;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public Attachment Diploma {
        get {
            if(Diploma == null)
                Diploma = new Attachment();
            return Diploma;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public FormClass(){
        
        //Empty constructor
    }
    
    /**
    Page redirects
    **/
    //Basic Info
    public PageReference step1() {
        
        return Page.TestForm;
    }
    
    //Address
    public PageReference step2() {
        
        return Page.Step2;
    }
    
    //User uploads NYS ID
    public PageReference step3(){
        
        return Page.Step3;
    }
    
    //Employment details
    public PageReference step4(){
        
        return Page.UploadID;
    }
    
    public PageReference step5(){
        
        return Page.Employment;
    }
    
    public PageReference step6(){
        
        return Page.Education;
    }
    
    public PageReference step7(){
        
        return Page.UploadDiploma;
    }
    
    public PageReference step8(){
        
        return Page.Application1;
    }
    
    public PageReference step9(){
        
        return Page.Application2;
    }
    
    public PageReference step10(){
        
        return Page.Application3;
    }
    
    public PageReference step11(){
        
        return Page.Submit;
    }
    
    //Save application to Salesforce
    public PageReference saveApplication(){
        
        try {
        upsert app;
        ID.ParentId = app.Id;
        Diploma.ParentId = app.Id;
        insert ID;
        insert Diploma;
        } catch(DMLException e) {
            Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, 'No such combination exists'));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, the short answer to your question is YES; I would suggest you use [edit] and reduce the scope of the problem down to two steps rather than ten. If you are not seeing the record and you know that step11 is being called, it is possible your markup on the last page is missing `apex:pageMessages`

Comment: Thanks.  Someone suggested setting `setRedirect` to false and preserving the view state of the VFP - is this causing the issue as well?

The reason there are 11 pages is because I am trying to maximize the user experience by not having a long scroll of questions (this is a public facing form for my client's potential clients)

Comment: sorry, you misunderstood me; i suggest 2 steps solely for the purposes of debugging and reducing the size of the problem down. Also, see the [official doc on how to do wizards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm)

Comment: Ah no problem! I saw the wizards reference on SF, but they are using 4 different objects whereas in my case I am only trying to create one (long) record with a multi-step form.

I will try to recreate the problem with 2 steps